# export filenames to temp file bash

Tags: regex, bash, unix, filenames

I have a lot of files in multiple directories that all have the following setup for the filename:

```
prob123456_01
```

I want to delete the trailing "_01" off of each file name and export them to a temp file.  How exactly would I delete the trailing "_01" as well as export? I am rather new to scripting so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by _export them to a temp file_? Do you mean that each of the file names should be printed to the file? Could you also be more explicit about the pattern each file name follows?

Comment: How do you want to represent the filenames in the temporary file? Note that filenames on UNIX can contain literal newlines, so trying to separate a stream of filenames by putting newlines between them is open to abuse by an attacker with control over those names.

Answer (score 2):

As you've tagged with [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), I'll assume that you can use `globstar`

```
shopt -s globstar # enable globstar
for f in **_[0-9][0-9]; do echo "${f%_*}"; done > tmp
```

With `globstar` enabled, the pattern `**_[0-9][0-9]` matches any file ending in `_`, followed by any 2 digit number, in the current directory and any subdirectories. `${f%_*}` removes the end of the file name using bash's built-in string manipulation functionality.

Better yet, as [Charles Duffy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14122/charles-duffy) suggests (thanks), you can use an array instead of a loop:

```
files=( **_[0-9][0-9] ); printf '%s\n' "${files[@]%_*}"
```

The array is filled the filenames that match the same pattern as before. `${files[@]%_*}` removes the last part from each element of the array and passes them all as arguments to `printf`, which prints each result on a separate line.

Either of these approaches is likely to be quicker than using `find` as everything is done in the shell, without executing any separate processes.

Previously I had suggested to use the pattern `**_{00..99}`, although this is not ideal for a couple of reasons. It is less efficient, as it expands to `**_00`, `**_01`, `**_02`, `...`, `**_99`. Also, any of those 100 patterns that don't match will be included literally in the output unless another option, `nullglob` is enabled.

It's up to you whether you use `[0-9]` or `[[:digit:]]` but the advantage of the latter is that it matches all characters defined to be a digit, which may vary depending on your locale. If this isn't a concern, I would go with the former.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want a list of the filenames without the trailing `_01`. The following would do that:

```
find . -type f -name '*_01' | sed 's/_01$//' > tmp.lst
```

`find . -type f -name '*_01'` looks for all the files in the current directory, and its descendent directories, for files with names ending in `_01`.

`|` is the so-called pipe, handing the results of the left-hand call to the right-hand call.

`sed 's/_01$//'` removes the `_01` from the end of each filename.

`> tmp.lst` writes the result into the file `tmp.lst`

These are all pretty basic parts of working with `bash` and its likes, so it might be a good idea to look at a tutorial or two and familiarize yourself with those and a few others ;)

Comment: Thank you! I've been trying to familiarize myself but I became stumped a little.  Also, what would I do to modify the find statement to find any files that have "_" followed by any two integers at the end? (not just 01)

Comment: @Will you could change the pattern to `'*_[0-9][0-9]'`